# what virtual machine should dell poweredg sc 1425 install?

Tags: oracle, virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I'm building our local server and want to use virtual machines but it seems VMware ESXi is not compatible with our hardware:

- Server: Dell SC 1424
- CPU : 2 Xeon 3.2G (buss 800, cache L2 2M)
- Ram: 6G DDR ECC 266
- Hard disk: 2 Hitachi Sata 1TB. Raid Dell Cerc 2s ( raid 0, 1)
- Nic: 2 Broadcom 1Gb/s

Does anyone have any suggestions about compatible virtualization software for our server? I wanted to use the server for various purposes like web hosting, subversion and to test different server OSs.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install ESXi 3.5 on an SC1425 running from a USB key. You will not be able to run anything higher than that due to increased hardware constraints in ESXi 4+

Also, an important thing to note with those Xeons: **They do not have the VT flag, which means you will NOT be able to run x64 VMs.**

..and of course, no one will ever support this running in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You're right this server isn't on the [VMware hardware compatibility list](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php).  If you have something else that is on the list you can use that but your best bet is [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/) (also free).  It runs on top of Windows or Linux and can use any platform.  I would recommend that you look at getting more RAM for that server because it's VERY easy to use 6GB of RAM with just one or two VMs.

Answer (score 0):

With such a small amount of memory I would recommend OpenVZ